# Display Array Object in Flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, object

hope you guys have a great day!

I'am learning Flutter, and now i got some obstacle to display data from array object, so i have the array object look like this:

```
// i saved this array object to listLorem var
listLorem = [
    {
        "ids": 12,
        "someText": "Lorem Ipsum #12",
    },
    {
        "ids": 11,
        "someText": "Lorem Ipsum #11",
    },
]
```

and then, i want to display it on my DropDownItems, somethins looks like this:

```
items: [
 DropdownMenuItem(                                                          
  child: Text("Choose One"),
  value: "",
 ),
 listLorem.map((items) => DropdownMenuItem(
  child: Text(items.someText),
  value: items.ids,
 )),
],
```

====== EDIT =========

and this is my console said (with all red)

```
listLorem((items) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                                                                          ^
: Error: The argument type 'List<Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'.
register.dart:569
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'DropdownMenuItem' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart' ('../../../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart').
```

i've tried others method, but i still didn't know how to do it right, i got `"redline"` all over the place :(

Comment: Add your flutter console log

Comment: hey @AlexSunderSingh, i added my console to the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be as following

```
items: [
 DropdownMenuItem(                                                          
  child: Text("Choose One"),
  value: "",
 ),
 ...listLorem.map((items) => DropdownMenuItem(
  child: Text(items.someText),
  value: items.ids,
 )),//...(triple dots) is represents list is getting appended
],
```

Or

````
items: [
 DropdownMenuItem(                                                          
  child: Text("Choose One"),
  value: 0,
 ),
 ...listLorem.map((items) => DropdownMenuItem(
  child: Text(items.someText),
  value: items.ids,
 )),//...(triple dots) is represents list is getting appended
],```
````